# How, in Gitlab CI, to share very large data between pipelines for jobs running on the same runner?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab

How, in Gitlab CI, to share very large data between pipelines for jobs running on the same runner?

Clarification of terms:

- "share" means the data must be available on the same filesystem (accessible by build scripts)
- "very large" means approx 5GB
- "data" means cloned, of other then actual, project repository (i.e. the actual project depends on the "other")
- "same runner" means the jobs run from different pipelines (rawly i.e. pipeline=build run)

I already tried [Gitlab-Ci: How could I share data between jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50358923/gitlab-ci-how-could-i-share-data-between-jobs) but this does not suit my requirements as it share data between jobs, but not between pipelines.

I expect following:

- in job specification (or from script invoked by the job specification) would be able to access some common/shared folder, where I would be able to clone/fetch/pull the "other" repository
- then I would be able to make symbolic links from the main repository to particular locations in the "other" (shared) repository