# Gitlab artifacts and untracked

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, artifacts

What is the use of `artifacts:untracked` in the `artifacts`?
I see that untracked files e.g. binaries are part of the artifacts without setting `untracked: true`.
So what is the use of it?

Answer (score 7):

By default, when you define artifacts in a job, any files specified in `.gitignore` will be ignored and not included in the artifact.

Setting `untracked: true` will not use `.gitignore`, i.e. all untracked files will be included. Since `untracked: false` is the default, adding that won't do anything.

You can find more information at [artifacts:untracked](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifactsuntracked).

Answer (score 1):

`artifacts:untracked` ignores configuration in the repository’s `.gitignore` file.

If you use `untracked: false`, the artifacts won't have any files/folders ignored by `.gitignore`.