# gitlab-ci - jobs with multiple stages for different branches

Tags: gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

Following Szenario.
I've got 1 production and 2 development branches which should be deployed with different environment variables

```
- prod
- dev1
- dev2
```

I want to separate the deploy into 2 different stages

```
- build
- deploy
```

How to configure the gitlab-ci file, to store the scripts and stages for each branch?

I've tried several things but do not get a valid working ci.

```
 stages:
 - build
 - deploy

 variables:
 IMAGE: my_image

 # Production
 prod:
   stage: build
   script:
   - docker build -t $IMAGE --build-arg RAILS_ENV=production .
   only:
   - prod

   stage: deploy
   script:
   - docker push $IMAGE
   - docker run -e "some production relevated env vars"
   only:
   - prod

 # Development 1
 dev1:
   stage: build
   script:
   - docker build -t $IMAGE --build-arg RAILS_ENV=staging .
   only:
   - dev1

   stage: deploy
   script:
   - docker push $IMAGE
   - docker run -e "some dev1 relevated env vars"
   only:
   - dev1

 # Development 2
 dev2:
   stage: build
   script:
   - docker build -t $IMAGE --build-arg RAILS_ENV=staging .
   only:
   - dev2

   stage: deploy
   script:
   - docker push $IMAGE
   - docker run -e "some dev2 relevated env vars"
   only:
   - dev2
```

Is there a possibility to split Jobs that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.
Just add a Job for each environment.

```
 stages:
 - build
 - deploy

 variables:
 IMAGE: my_image

 # Production
 prod-build:
   stage: build
   script:
   - docker build -t $IMAGE --build-arg RAILS_ENV=production .
   only:
   - prod

 prod-deploy:
   stage: deploy
   script:
   - docker push $IMAGE
   - docker run -e "some production relevated env vars"
   only:
   - prod

 # Development 1
 dev1-build:
   stage: build
   script:
   - docker build -t $IMAGE --build-arg RAILS_ENV=staging .
   only:
   - dev1

 dev2-deploy:
   stage: deploy
   script:
   - docker push $IMAGE
   - docker run -e "some dev1 relevated env vars"
   only:
   - dev1

 # Development 2
 dev2-build:
   stage: build
   script:
   - docker build -t $IMAGE --build-arg RAILS_ENV=staging .
   only:
   - dev2

 dev2-deploy:
   stage: deploy
   script:
   - docker push $IMAGE
   - docker run -e "some dev2 relevated env vars"
   only:
   - dev2
```

Comment: You should use dependencies and artifacts as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38155856/5994580

Comment: what if we want to use the same container for running the next stage