# How to relate stages in gitlab ci with laravel?

Tags: laravel, continuous-integration, gitlab, yaml, cd

I have two stages in my gitlab ci .yml

The first stage is called **Build**, which run laravel's commands like:

```
php artisan key:generate
php artisan migrate
...
```

and the second stage is **Test**, which I attempted to run this:

```
php vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-text --colors=never
```

that everything is fine until the Test stage running. It occur an error which said:

```
There's no encryption key.
```

and the Thing is I did **php artisan key:generate** in last stage but how I can relate last stage commands to the current or next stages?

I mean I want to move 'php artisan key:generate' that had been entered in build stage to the test stage, and I won't need it anymore ( I mean I don't want to execute it again in test stage )

Comment: It seems like you're trying to pass artifacts from one stage to another. Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38155856/7528944) help with your question?

Comment: @PtrTon I mean I want to move 'php artisan key:generate' that had been entered in build stage to the test stage, and I won't need it anymore ( I mean I don't want to execute it again in test stage )