# Sonarcloud shows 0% coverage on new code, and also shows 0% coverage on master branch with gitlab ci

Tags: gitlab, code-coverage, coverage.py, sonarcloud

I am using GitLab ci to run SonarCloud code analysis on the code.

here is my gitlab-ci.yaml

```yaml
stages:
  - test

before_script:
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh &&
    cp $gitlab_private_key ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 &&
    chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 &&
    touch ~/.ssh/known_hosts &&
    ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/``known_hosts

variables:
  SONAR_USER_HOME: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.sonar"  # Defines the location of the analysis task cache
  GIT_DEPTH: "0"  # Tells git to fetch all the branches of the project, required by the analysis task
  GITLAB_PROJECT_ID: ${CI_PROJECT_ID} # needed to be exported to the project's environments
  FLASK_APP: manage.py

sonarcloud-check:
  image:
    name: sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  cache:
    key: "${CI_JOB_NAME}"
    paths:
      - .sonar/cache
  script:
    - sonar-scanner
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - master

test-merge-request-changes:
  stage: test
  only:
    - merge_requests
  image:
    name: docker:19.03.13-git
  services:
    - name: docker:19.03.0-dind
      entrypoint: ["env", "-u", "DOCKER_HOST"]
      command: ["dockerd-entrypoint.sh"]
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    ENV: test
    CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true"
  before_script:
    - echo $CI_BUILD_TOKEN | docker login -u gitlab-ci-token --password-stdin ${CI_REGISTRY}
  script:
    - echo "Running Tests..."
    - cp ${group_shared_vars} ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.env
    - docker build . -f Dockerfile-testing -t test_merge_req --build-arg GITLAB_PROJECT_ID=${GITLAB_PROJECT_ID}
    - docker run --cidfile="my-package.txt" test_merge_req:latest

  after_script:
    - touch text2.txt
    - docker cp $(cat my-package.txt):/app/tests/coverage/coverage.xml coverage.xml
    - docker cp $(cat my-package.txt):/app/tests/coverage/junit.xml junit.xml
  timeout: 2h
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      cobertura:
        - coverage.xml
      junit:
        - junit.xml
  coverage: '/TOTAL.*\s+(\d+%)$/'
```

And here is my `sonar-project.properties`

```
sonar.projectKey=my_app-key
sonar.organization=my_org

sonar.sources=lib
sonar.tests=tests
sonar.exclusions=tests
sonar.language=python
sonar.python.version=3.8
```

I want to get the report that is generated in the container analyzed by sonarcloud on each merge request.

Also, when a code is pushed to the master branch, I want to get the coverage percent on sonarcloud of the project to be updated but it just shows 0%.

Is there any way that after the merge requests are run, we get the sonarcloud analysis on the report of the docker container?

And also getting the master branch coverage updated without having to commit the `coverage.xml` to the repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging into how Gitlab CI stages and jobs work and also the insight that [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56550870/11207358) brought, I have tweaked the above GitLab ci so that it :

1. First runs the tests
2. Then uploads the coverage outputs into the path specified for the artifacts
3. Then in the next stage, it pulls those artifacts
4. Replaces the `path` that was replaced by `pytest-cov` in the `<source>...</source>` with a `sed` command. (This step is due to the path that was placed into the source element is relevant to the docker container and then after downloading the coverage report not working inside the GitLab ci container)
5. Running the `sonar-scanner` on the coverage report.

GitLab ci:

```yaml
stages:
  - build_test
  - analyze_test

before_script:
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh &&
    cp $gitlab_private_key ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 &&
    chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 &&
    touch ~/.ssh/known_hosts &&
    ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/``known_hosts

variables:
  SONAR_USER_HOME: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.sonar"  # Defines the location of the analysis task cache
  GIT_DEPTH: "0"  # Tells git to fetch all the branches of the project, required by the analysis task
  GITLAB_PROJECT_ID: ${CI_PROJECT_ID} # needed to be exported to the projects environments

include:
  - template: Code-Quality.gitlab-ci.yml

test-merge-request:
  stage: build_test
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - master
  image:
    name: docker:19.03.13-git
  cache:
    key: "${CI_JOB_NAME}"
    paths:
      - build
  services:
    - name: docker:19.03.0-dind
      entrypoint: ["env", "-u", "DOCKER_HOST"]
      command: ["dockerd-entrypoint.sh"]
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    ENV: test
    CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true"
  before_script:
    - echo $CI_BUILD_TOKEN | docker login -u gitlab-ci-token --password-stdin ${CI_REGISTRY}
  script:
    - echo "Running Tests..."
    - cp ${group_shared_vars} ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.env
    - docker build . -f Dockerfile-testing -t test_merge_req --build-arg GITLAB_PROJECT_ID=${GITLAB_PROJECT_ID}
    - docker run --cidfile="my-package.txt" test_merge_req:latest
  after_script:
    - docker cp $(cat my-package.txt):/app/tests/coverage/coverage.xml build/coverage.xml
    - docker cp $(cat my-package.txt):/app/tests/coverage/junit.xml build/junit.xml
  timeout: 2h
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - build
    reports:
      cobertura:
        - build/coverage.xml
      junit:
        - build/junit.xml
    expire_in: 30 min
  coverage: '/TOTAL.*\s+(\d+%)$/'

sonarcloud-check:
  stage: analyze_test
  image:
    name: sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  cache:
    key: "${CI_JOB_NAME}"
    paths:
      - .sonar/cache
  script:
    - echo "Logging coverage..."
    - sed -i "s|<source>\/app\/my_app<\/source>|<source>$CI_PROJECT_DIR\/my_app<\/source>|g" ./build/coverage.xml
    - sonar-scanner
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - master
  dependencies:
    - test-merge-request-changes
```

The takeaway from my issue was that Gitlab doesn't share the artifacts between the jobs that are placed in one GitLab ci stage, but rather shares them between different stages.

So, I just created two separate stages, one for building the tests (`build_test`) and one for analyzing the tests (`analyze_test`). Then, made the `sonar-cloud` job dependent on the `test-merge-request-changes` job. This way, we make sure that first the tests runs in the `test-merge-request-changes` and then the uploaded artifacts are utilized inside the `sonar-cloud` stage.