# Use GitLab SAST report JSON later in same pipeline

Tags: gitlab

I'm trying to use an artifact from the [Gitlab SAST pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/sast/) later in the same pipeline. Specifically, `gl-sast-report.json` which is from the template: `Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml` expanded below from GitLab's Pipeline "Full Configuration" view:

```yaml
# GitLab Stuff
stages:
  - ".pre"
  - test
  - build
  - ".post"

nodejs-scan-sast:
  stage: test
  artifacts:
    reports:
      sast:
        - gl-sast-report.json
  rules:
    - if: "$SAST_DISABLED == 'true' || $SAST_DISABLED == '1'"
      when: never
    - if: "$SAST_EXCLUDED_ANALYZERS =~ /nodejs-scan/"
      when: never
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"
      exists:
        - "**/package.json"
  variables:
    SEARCH_MAX_DEPTH: 4
    SAST_ANALYZER_IMAGE_TAG: 4
    SAST_ANALYZER_IMAGE: "$SECURE_ANALYZERS_PREFIX/nodejs-scan:$SAST_ANALYZER_IMAGE_TAG"
  script:
    - "/analyzer run"
  extends: ".sast-analyzer"
  allow_failure: true
  image:
    name: "$SAST_ANALYZER_IMAGE"

# My Stuff
parse-sast-report:
  image: pcfens/sast-parser
  stage: build
  dependencies:
    - nodejs-scan-sast
  script:
    - pwd
    - ls -lAh .
    - find / -iname "*sast*"
    - python /app/parse-sast.py gl-sast-report.json
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - sast_report.html
```

I'm trying to follow [this Stack Overflow answer/example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38155856/1304462), but the problem is that the `gl-sast-report.json` doesn't show up when `parse-sast-report` runs (you can see me looking for it with the `ls` and `find` commands). How do I get the `gl-sast-report.json` artifact to show up in a later step in my pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To workaround it you have to use [artifacts:paths](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#artifactspaths) keyword:

```
nodejs-scan-sast:
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - gl-sast-report.json
    reports:
      sast:
        - gl-sast-report.json
```

At the moment there is the [open issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/243717) about this behavior.

Comment: Ah yes, very confusing, thanks for the clarification. I see it mentioned in the GitLab Docs in one small line: "You cannot download artifact reports with the job artifacts API, unless the report is added as a regular artifact with artifacts:paths."

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_artifacts.html#:~:text=You%20cannot%20download%20artifact%20reports%20with%20the%20job%20artifacts%20API%2C%20unless%20the%20report%20is%20added%20as%20a%20regular%20artifact%20with%20artifacts%3Apaths.